# How do I assign stderr into a local variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running a Python script from within a Bash script and have been trying to assign that command's `stderr` into a Bash variable. I think the issue is with how I'm referencing the variable, but am having trouble trying to identify what that problem is...

Here's what I'm doing and what I've tried:

```
#errorMessage=""


python test.py 2> $errorMessage

echo $errorMessage
```

Results in error code: `test.sh: line 4: $errorMessage: ambiguous redirect`

And with errorMessage actually declared, I get the same error message:

```
errorMessage=""


python test.py 2> $errorMessage

echo $errorMessage
```

The python file `test.py` is set to write to stderr. I'm ultimately trying to check if this variable `errorMessage` is empty or not to do more error handling; is checking the length of `errorMessage` fine?

Comment: `2>$errorMessage` redirects to the **file** named by the contents of the variable `errorMessage`. An empty string isn't a valid filename, hence "ambiguous redirect".

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. From reading the link that my question seems to be a duplicate of, everyone there answered with redirecting to a file. So I'm guessing redirecting to a variable is not allowed at all?

Comment: There are absolutely answers in that question that use command substitutions to capture stderr, rather than redirecting to files. Look harder.

Comment: ...that said, the reason the *accepted* answer there redirects to a file is because the OP wanted to be able to run stdout into a larger pipeline, and doing *that* in conjunction with capturing stderr is a lot more difficult.

Comment: ...actually, if I had to guess at a cause of the misunderstanding... perhaps you're reading `2>&1` as redirecting to a file named `1` or `&1`? That's not what it does.

Comment: (That said -- if your `test.py` were correctly written, it would be reflecting whether or not it exited in an error -- or if whatever test it was running was successful -- in its *exit status*, so you wouldn't need to check contents written to stderr to make this determination).

Comment: Yeah so it looks like most people had their command wrapped into a variable, like the top accepted answer. I'm still a little confused since they're redirecting to stdout, which I don't need to do. Is this fine?: `errorMessage=$( { python test.py } 2 )`

Comment: You **do** actually need to redirect to stdout: stdout is the only thing that's captured in a command substitution. Thus, it's the only thing assigned to the variable. `errorMessage=$( python test.py 2>&1 >/dev/null )` will thus discard the original stdout, but capture the original stderr into the variable named `errorMessage`.

Comment: Okay, so command substitution is still the only way to do this? Or is there another way that I'm just not aware of?

Comment: "only way" is a little bit strong of a phrase -- there are answers other than command substitution, but they're *bad* answers -- unidiomatic code with significant caveats. (I don't really agree that it's accurate to describe a command substitution as "wrapped in a variable", btw -- you're storing the command's output, not the command itself).

Comment: As an example of one of those unidiomatic answers: `IFS= read -r -d '' errorMessage < <(python test.py 2>&1 >/dev/null && printf '\0')` will do the job, but it's bash-only and cuts off output at the first literal NUL if any exist.